# How to set Flask SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI with username and password captured from url

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

How do i configure in flask app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] the username, password and db_name with values captured from url previously.

Example, my app first ask for username, password and db_name and after i want it use then to setup SQLAlchemy.

How do i achieve this?

The reason is that i need to validate against mssql server because all the user names and password they are all there.
I'll appreciate all your help.
Thanks anticipated.

Comment: Seems like in your case it's better to use a plain Sqlalchemy than Flask-Sqlalchemy because Flask-Sqlalchemy is built around a single or limited db connections which are established on startup but your case require dynamic connections and is close to multi-tenant model.

Comment: Thanks Fian for your attention, but all my SQLAlchemy are based on Flask-SQLAlchemy ORM structure and i need a solutions based on that.

Comment: This SO question, [Flask SQLAlchemy setup dynamic URI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14491678/2800058) might give you some ideas.

Answer (score -1):

To Support PostgreSQL with SQLAlchemy, follow these steps:

- Install [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/)
  `pip install psycopg2`
- Configure the connection URL :
  Construct the connection URL with the appropriate parameters - {user}, {password}, {host}, {port}, and {dbname}.

URL format:

```
postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@host:port/dbname[?key=value&key=value...]
```

For instance, if your PostgreSQL setup includes the following configuration:

- Host: localhost
- Port: 5433
- User: postgres
- Password: P@ssw0rd (note: replace @ with %40)
- Database name: postgres

Your URL would look like this:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = r"postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:P%40ss0rd@localhost:5433/postgres"
```

For further information, refer to the [official SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2).